# Android JetPack navigation with multiple stack

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I'm using Jetpack Navigation `version 1.0.0-alpha04` with bottom navigation. It works but the navigation doesn't happen correctly. For example, if I have tab A and tab B and from tab A I go to Page C and from there I go to tab B and come back to tab A again, I will see root fragment in the tab A and not page C which does not what I expect.

I'm looking for a solution to have a different stack for each tab, so the state of each tab is reserved when I come back to it, Also I don't like to keep all this fragment in the memory since it has a bad effect on performance, Before jetpack navigation, I used this library https://github.com/ncapdevi/FragNav, That does exactly what, Now I'm looking for the same thing with jetpack navigation.

Comment: Can you post your activity's onCreate and OnNavigationItemSelectedListener code? It will help to see what you've already tried.

Comment: what is page in this context? another activity? or a view within tab a? maybe a pager?

Comment: @NickCardoso page is a fragment, I have root fragments in each tab and when some event happens we go to next fragment in that tab.

Comment: @Reza Did you find any solution ?

Comment: @Armin not yet! I'll be interested in a better answer though. So if you find anything let me know as well.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 16):

**EDIT 2:** Though still no first class support (as of writing this), Google has now updated their samples with an example of how they think this should be solved for now: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/NavigationAdvancedSample

---

The major reason is you only use one `NavHostFragment` to hold the whole back stack of the app.

The solution is that each tab should hold its own back stack.

- In your main layout, wrap each tab fragment with a `FrameLayout`.
- Each tab fragment is a `NavHostFragment` and contains its own navigation graph in order to make each tab fragment having its own back stack.
- Add a `BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` to `BottomNavigtionView` to handle the visibility of each FrameLayout.

This also takes care of your "...I don't like to keep all this fragment in memory...", because a Navigation with `NavHostFragment` by default uses `fragmentTransaction.replace()`, i.e. you will always only have as many fragments as you have `NavHostFragment`s. The rest is just in the back stack of your navigation graph.

**Edit:** Google is working on a native implementation https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80029773#comment25

---

**More in detail**

Let's say you have a `BottomNavigationView` with 2 menu choices, `Dogs` and `Cats`.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/dogMenu"
        .../>

    <item android:id="@+id/catMenu"
        .../>
</menu>
```

Then you need 2 navigation graphs, say `dog_navigation_graph.xml` and `cat_navigation_graph.xml`.

The `dog_navigation_graph` might look like

```
<navigation
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/dog_navigation_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/dogMenu">
</navigation>
```

and the corresponding for `cat_navigation_graph`.

In your `activity_main.xml`, add 2 `NavHostFragment`s

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_dog"
    ...>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/dog_navigation_host_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/dog_navigation_graph"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

and underneath add the corresponding for your cat `NavHostFragment`. On your cat frame layout, set `android:visibility="invisible"`

Now, in your `MainActivity`'s `onCreateView` you can

```
bottom_navigation_view.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.dogMenu -> showHostView(host = 0)
        R.id.catMenu -> showHostView(host = 1)
    }
    return@setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
}
```

All that `showHostView()` is doing is toggling the visibility of your `FrameLayout`s that are wrapping the `NavHostFragment`s. So make sure to save them in some way, e.g. in `onCreateView`

```
val hostViews = arrayListOf<FrameLayout>()  // Member variable of MainActivity
hostViews.apply {
    add(findViewById(R.id.frame_dog))
    add(findViewById(R.id.frame_cat))
}
```

Now it's easy to toggle which `hostViews` should be visible and invisible.

Comment: It may work but If I do this I have five fragments in the memory at the same time while only one of them is used. What do you suggest to fix this?

Comment: Yeah, that's how you get a good user experience :). Either way, if the user navigates around the app, you want to keep each back stack.. And wasn't that the question to begin with?

Comment: Well, What I'm trying to achieve is to have separate back stack while only having one fragment at the memory, other fragments exists only in the stack. I know its hard but It should be possible, you can check this out for example https://github.com/ncapdevi/FragNav

Comment: Oh, true, now I see your point. That's a nuance worth thinking about! Maybe a `ViewPager` is the way to go, but I haven't tried that with Navigation yet. I'll have to take a look at that.

Comment: @Reza I though about your point when I wasn't feeling as tired as the first time, and it struck me that there never was an issue. I've updated the answer with an explanation (see `fragmentTransaction.replace()`), and added a full code example.

Comment: @Algar Is there any update related to this approach?

Answer (score 1):

The issue has been resolved by the Android team in the latest version 2.4.0-alpha01 multiple backstacks along with bottom navigation support is now possible without any workaround.

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation

Comment: Please how can I implement the new version?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68042591/problem-upgrading-my-fragments-navigation-versionfrom-2-3-5-to-2-4-0-alpha03

Comment: @RichardWilson Just add the two dependencies

Comment: @ArsalanFakhar But we can't use alpha library in production so can you suggest any other alternative?

Answer (score 0):

First, I want to make an edit to @Algar's answer. The frame that you want to hide should have `android:visibility="gone"` instead of `invisible`. The reason for that in your main layout you would have something like this:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".ui.activity.MainActivity">
    
        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar_base" />
    
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_home"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            >
            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/home_navigation_host_fragment"
                android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:defaultNavHost="true"
                app:navGraph="@navigation/home_nav" />
        </FrameLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_find"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:visibility="gone">
    
            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/find_navigation_host_fragment"
                android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:defaultNavHost="true"
                app:navGraph="@navigation/find_nav" />
        </FrameLayout>
        ...
    
   </LinearLayout>
```

If you wrap your main in a LinearLayout, setting the frame to invisible still make that frame counts, so the BottomNavigation wont appear.

Second, you should create a NavHostFragment instance (ie: curNavHostFragment) to keep track of which NavHostFragment is being visible when a tab in BottomNavigation is clicked. **Note**: you may want to restore this curNavHostFragment when the activity is destroyed by configuration's changes. This is an example:

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    //if this activity is restored from previous state,
    //we will have the ItemId of botnav the has been selected
    //so that we can set up nav controller accordingly
    switch (bottomNav.getSelectedItemId()) {
        case R.id.home_fragment:
            curNavHostFragment = homeNavHostFragment;
            ...
            break;
        case R.id.find_products_fragment:
            curNavHostFragment = findNavHostFragment;
            ...
            break;
    
    }
    curNavController = curNavHostFragment.getNavController();
```