# Android Jetpack Navigation proper back stack with BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, bottomnavigationview, android-navigation, android-jetpack

**OBS:** Though still no first class support (as of writing this), Google has now updated their samples with an example of how they think this should be solved: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/NavigationAdvancedSample

The [Android Codelab for Navigation](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-navigation/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0) does a good job describing how to use the architecture component Navigation together with a `BottomNavigationView`. But let's say I have 2 tabs in the `BottomNavigationView`, **Tab1** and **Tab2**. And let's say that in **Tab1** you navigate through the fragments **Frag1** --> **Frag2**. Now, whenever I go to **Tab2**, and then back to **Tab1**, the fragment back stack of **Frag1,2** is gone, and replaced with the starting point **Frag1** again.

What do I have to do in an app so that a `BottomNavigationView` together with [Navigation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/) keeps its back stack intact even though I change tabs? And, also keeping the back/up button behaviours in sync with the guidelines.

Previously I've done this with the use of `ViewPager` and managing the back stack my selfe, but that doesn't feels like the right approach with the new Navigation.

Thanks in advance!

---

**Edit:**

There's a more elaborate answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51707889/android-jetpack-navigation-with-multiple-stack/52146506#52146506).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The major reason is you only use one `NavHostFragment` to hold the whole back stack of the app.

So the solution is each tab should hold its own back stack.

- In your main layout, wrap each tab fragment with a `FrameLayout`.
- Each tab fragment is a `NavHostFragment` and contains its own navigation graph in order to make each tab fragment having its own back stack.
- Add a `BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` to `BottomNavigtionView` to handle the visibility of each `FrameLayout`.

---

If you don't want to keep all the fragments in memory, you can use `app:popUpTo` and `app:popUpToInclusive="true"` to pop out the ones you don't want to keep.

Comment: That's indeed an interesting approach - to toggle the visibility in that way. I will try it later today and return with an Accept if it feels right. Thanks in the meantime!

Comment: I can't say I'm a big fan of always having up to 5 fragments active all the time (though most of them isn't visible). Doesn't it feel like a better approach in that case to use a `ViewPager` instead? In that way, you're only keeping the back stack, and not the whole inflated fragment it selfe. Any thoughts on that @jaychang0917?

Comment: @jaychang0917 can you please explain how would I use `app:popUpTo` and `app:popUpToInclusive="true"`?

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not supported in the new Navigation Architecture. I was also pretty bummed by this, as it is a very basic feature in today's apps, and a lot of the apps are now using the bottom navigation. There is a running thread, if you wanna keep an eye on it. They are saying they will come up with a long term solution for this, but for the shorter run, they are gonna give a sample on how to tackle this. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80029773#comment25

Comment: This is official workaround by Google for this problem
https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/NavigationAdvancedSample